# About "show interface switchport" output

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, cisco-commands, vtp

The `show interface switchport` command shows a specific row `Pruning VLANs Enabled`. The field description is `Lists the VLANs that are pruning-eligible` but I cannot understand what that row is meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With VTP, you can mark VLANs as eligible to be pruned for a trunk link. When pruning is enabled in VTP, the eligible VLANs will be pruned if there is nothing downstream of the trunk link using those VLANs.

[This Cisco document](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/nx-os/layer2/configuration/guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_7000_Series_NX-OS_Layer_2_Switching_Configuration_Guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_7000_Series_NX-OS_Layer_2_Switching_Configuration_Guide_chapter_0101.html#concept_E644838A406843419A14A8FB2791D1E1) shows how to configure VTP pruning and how to add VLANs to the pruning eligible list.

```
switch(config-if)# switchport trunk pruning vlan [add | remove | except | none | all] VLAN-IDs
```

It is a good practice to prune VLANs from links where they are not needed. This will eliminate broadcast traffic for those VLANs being sent to switches which don't have those VLANs.